# StreamReader into DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, atom-feed

I want to read atom xml, and used following code

```
string str1 = "http://moss:133333/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Document Library/OrdersExcel.xlsx/Model/Tables('Table1')?$format=atom";

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str1);
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0)";

WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();              

Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);
string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
```

The last line in above code basically reads whole stream reader into the string `Response`.

Now I do not know how do I read the above string's atom xml into the data table.

Comment: Can't you parse the XML document using classes defined in `System.Xml`?

Comment: You don't need a StreamReader, just feed the data to `XElement.Load(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`DataTable.ReadXml` reads XML schema and data into the DataTable using the specified TextReader.

```
var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(xmlStream);
var newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.ReadXml(reader);
```